# Angular js 4 with VS Code showing error on npm start command in powershell

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

[image: *enter image description here*]

I am new in angular js 4. I have already installed node and trying to code using VS Code. But when trying to start simple application with first command in powershell npm start it shows error attached in screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, either you didn't install angular-cli or You dont have admin rights to serve the application . If that is the case open node command prompt (search with node , you will find node.js command prompt,select that ) and serve your application from that by going to application folder.

Comment: You're right, I don't have admin rights. With your suggestion how to serve my application, I open node cmd prompt

Comment: open node command prompt. type cd <project folder path>. then do npm start

Answer (score 1):

As per error showing you need to install `angular cli` first in order to use their commands. so try to install CLI first by running the command

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

For more information please refer to official docs here

- https://cli.angular.io/
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

You need to install angular-cli globally in your machine.

`npm install -g @angular/cli`